# How to obtain a specific custom attribute when OfType is not available in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, custom-attributes, syncfusion

In my application I'm trying to obtain a specific attribute using a foreach loop:

Datasource of foreach:

[image]

Now I'd like to check for each property if it has the "EditTemplate" CustomAttribute, and if the property has it, put this attribute in a variable like this:

[image]

Foreach:

```
@foreach (var property in EditObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
      var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
      var DoSomeAttribute = attributes;

      //THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK BECAUSE .OfType is not recognized
      //var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<EditTemplateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The line of code "var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true)" giving me an object with x amount of items(Attributes within):

[image]

Now this is where I want to do a check if the attribute is of Type "EditTemplateAttribute", if this is the case I want to put it in a variable like this:

[image]

In another piece of code(and another foreach) I achieved this by:

```
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<EditTemplateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

However the .OfType is not available here.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<EditTemplateAttribute>();`

Comment: post code not screenshots

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay if i use your code i get error: ''System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute''

Comment: Have you added `using System.Reflection;`?

Comment: Yes but note that im foreaching through ".GetType().GetProperties()"

Comment: Nothing about your Case 2 picture is comprehensible. Replace it with the actual code you meant to discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why .OfType should be unavailable.
Try adding `using System.Linq`. This is the namespace where OfType extension method is defined.

I've noticed that your foreach is prefixed with '@'. Are you using MVC Razor view?
In that case you can add using like: `@using System.Linq`

In any case you can replace `.OfType<EditTemplateAttribute>()` with:

`.Where(x => x is EditTemplateAttribute).Select(x => (EditTemplateAttribute)x)`

Or you can use (may return attribute instance or null):

```
var someAttribute = (EditTemplateAttribute)attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x is EditTemplateAttribute);
```

Or, you can write your own OfType extension method (and use it like you wanted at first):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
  foreach (object obj in source)
  {
    if (obj is TResult)
      yield return (TResult) obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do the replacement I'm getting this error: "Cannot use lambda expression as an argument to dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it"

Comment: I'm foreaching over ".GetType().GetProperties()", maybe thats why?

Comment: I've edited the example code (Previously I forget to cast filtered attributes to EditTemplateAttribute).
The exception you are getting may indicate that you are using `dynamic` type. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, i fixed it by using "object" instead of dynamic. Your code worked!:)